# how to exclude the running executable C

Tags: c, executable

I'm writing a program dealing with directories and files. This program is going to open all accessible directories and read all accessible files under user input initial path.

The question is if the program opened the running executable, I will get seg fault, I'm wondering if there is any way that I could exclude the executable which is running but includes all other files? Given the condition that the program knows the name of executable but not knowing where the executable is gonna be nor the initial path

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Why do you believe opening the program file of the current program causes a segfault?

Comment: You shouldn't have that problem at all, even if it's the one you're executing. If you're getting a segfault, there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: @coelhudo Linux

Comment: @EOF because it was discussed in the class group chat and when I exclude all executable, the program ends up running well

Comment: @KenWhite so open a executable which is running won't cause seg fault?

Comment: Your class group chat delivers inaccurate information. I recommend trying authoritative documentation instead.

Comment: No, it won't. As I said, you've got something wrong in your code if you're getting a segfault.

Comment: As long as you're opening it only for reading. If you open it for writing, that will truncate the file and cause an error.

Comment: @Barmar: Possibly he used "r+" without knowing what it does.

Comment: @Joshua `r+` won't truncate, the modes beginning with `w` do.

Comment: Why are you opening lots of files? Possible problems is with number of file descriptors. that can be opened

Comment: @Barmar: But "r+" would open the file for write, which would fail if it was a running executable. Thus I gave my answer about checking the return from `fopen()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix you problem, check the return value of `fopen()`. If you can't open the file it returns `NULL` and puts a reason into `errno`. You can get the error message string with `strerror()`. Consider using `perror()` to output the error message as you loop through the files.

There's other possibilities like not handling really long lines, but this is by far the most likely problem.

This doesn't get the executable, but fixes the general segfault problem you're having which is a much more reasonable thing to do anyway.